# ANTLR Verilog @(*) matching two tokens

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to use ANTLR4 to parse Verilog code. I am using the Verilog grammar found here https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/verilog/Verilog2001.g4

The sample code is

```
module blinker(
        input clk,
        input rst,
        output blink
    );

    reg [24:0] counter_d, counter_q;

    assign blink = counter_q[24];

    always @(*) begin
        counter_d = counter_q + 1'b1;
    end

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (rst) begin
            counter_q <= 25'b0;
        end else begin
            counter_q <= counter_d;
        end
    end

endmodule
```

The problem is the line

```
always @(*) begin
```

The (*) is getting split into the tokens '(*' and ')'.

On line 723 of the grammar file there is

```
event_control :
'@' event_identifier
| '@' '(' event_expression ')'
| '@' '*'
| '@' '(' '*' ')'
;
```

Which should match the @(*) line if it wasn't for line 1329

```
attribute_instance : '(*' attr_spec ( ',' attr_spec )* '*)' ;
```

I'm new to all of this, but I'm guessing that the '(*' token from that line is matching the (* in the code and screwing things up.

After reading a bit from The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference, I thought that the rule first defined would take precedence. However, I think that it's doing a greedy match?

Any ideas on how to fix the grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm new to all of this, but I'm guessing that the `'(*'` token from that line is matching the `(*` in the code and screwing things up.

You are correct.

> After reading a bit from The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference, I thought that the rule first defined would take precedence. However, I think that it's doing a greedy match?

Although defined in parser rules, the literal tokens are really lexer rules, which take precedence in the order they're defined *only* in case they match the same amount of characters. If a lexer rule can match more, it does so (as you observed).

I don't know any Verilog, but a quick fix for it would be to let the `attribute_instance` look like:

```
attribute_instance : '(' '*' attr_spec ( ',' attr_spec )* '*' ')' ;
```

However, if the lexer discards characters, like spaces, then the input `"( *"` (parenthesis, space, star) would also be matched as the start of a `attribute_instance`. If that is not desirable, you could let your `event_control` look like this:

```
event_control 
 : '@' event_identifier
 | '@' '(' event_expression ')'
 | '@' '*'
 | '@' ( '(' '*' | '(*' ) ')'
 ;
```

Note the `( '(' '*' | '(*' )` in the last alternative, which matches two single tokens, `'('` and `'*'` (with possible spaces in between!), or the single token `'(*'`.

Comment: Since you can't have spaces in the '(*', you'd have to use your second option. However, that doesn't seem that great since seems strange to have the \* attached to the (. Is there no way to keep the '(\*' together for attributes and keep them separate for the event?

Comment: @EmbMicro why does it matter if the `(` and `*` are attached?

Comment: I haven't looked into actually using ANTLR for a practical purpose yet, but it seems like it would make it harder to figure out what's between the (). I guess as long as you can differentiate between the star and not star case you're ok.

Comment: @EmbMicro I don't see any issue: when processing the parse tree, you know when you're inside a `event_control` the (possible) single `(*` or `*)` can be considered as two tokens.

Comment: I had to use the line "| '@' (( '(' '\*' | '(\*' ) ')' |  '(' ('\*)' | '\*' ')' ))" instead to take care of the '\*)' token as well.

Answer (score 1):

I just tweaked The grammar as Bart has suggested. It seems to parse. I also removed some extra optional braces that were causing warnings. please try to pull down and do it again.
Ter

Comment: I see you went with the option to remove the '(\*' token. That allows the attribute_instance to be wrong. You can't have ( \* attrib \*), it must be (\* attrib \*). The other option of also matching the '(\*' tag for event_control doesn't seem like the correct way to do it either.

Comment: ah. we could add a Semantic predicate that simply checks the columns to make sure they are next to each other. I do that in the Java grammar for >> shift operator versus nested generics.

Comment: I just read the section of The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference (page 213) that talks about the >> problem and it says to just check it after everything is parsed for efficiency. It seems like the easiest solution is to use Bart Kiers solution and also match the (\* token.

Comment: cool. free free to alter my update in grammar. send a pull request.